# Баг верстки на мобильниках

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Доброго времени суток, столкнулся  с проблемой верстки и незнаю откуда ноги растут и как исправить

два одинаковых класса ведут себя по разному на мобильных устройствах,

1. все ок
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. а вот и баг
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   для мобильников использую  < meta name="viewport" content="width=1280">

баг замечен и на Anroid и на iOS.

Comment: Пожалуйста, перенесите информацию из документа по ссылке в свой вопрос. Здесь в том числе можно указывать и изображения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мобильные браузеры увеличивают текст в широких блоках. Добавьте к html

```
html {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; 
}
```

Более подробно об этом свойстве и его проблемах, но у себя такого не замечал http://habrahabr.ru/post/133465/

Answer (score 0):

Так срабатывает Font Boosting у мобильных браузеров.
Альтернативные способы решения. Задать viewport равной ширине экрана, добавив тег:

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Или указать в CSS:

```
html * {max-height: 1000000px;}
```